ssh doest not trigger source .bash_profiles
Using Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.
A server admin create my account, but it is little bit different with what I know. It seems like ssh does not trigger source $HOME/.bash_profile.
I think the account is not completed somehow.
How can I examine the problem
symptom:

.bash_profile does not work
source: not found
unable to auto-complete by tab key
prompt starts with $, not [user@localhost ~]$

How can I fix this account?
===== UPDATE =====
it comes out that login shell was not bash
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/sh

Can I set ssh to bash shell for a specific account?
Do not want to any side effects for other accounts or rebooting system or sshd service.

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reached End of Standard Support last year, and is thus off-topic on this site.  You can use ESM/Pro support options (cost maybe involved) if you wish but community support (such as this site) no longer exists, though SE Unix & Linux allow all Ubuntu questions too.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic or Canonical who provide ESM/Pro services.

Many shell options exist; plus (and related) there are many configs available that occur at login (for GUI or text logins, first login after boot or for each login etc) but the options don't exist for all shells.

Yes, you can set the shell to bash using chsh - see for example this related question Arrow keys, Home, End, tab-complete keys not working in shell

Like reply states, there would be lot of ways to change basic shell to bash. I solved my issue in following method.

generate .profile file in home directory
add exec bash in the file

so when ssh connected, it triggers .profile, then execute exec bash to change shell.
like @steeldriver mentioned, related question exists,
Arrow keys, Home, End, tab-complete keys not working in shell
